# Switch doesn't returns JSX

Tags: reactjs

`switch` in my component doesn't returns anything.
(I'm trying to make a `div` with social network icons).
I have `social()` function, first is checking props got {social} array, that contains network and link parameter. But when component mounts nothing in the `div`.

```
const ProfileInfo = (props) => {
  let social = () => {
    {
      if (props.social != null)
      {
        props.social.map((soc) => {
          switch (soc.network) {
            case "youtube": {
              return (
                <a href={soc.link}>
                  <Youtube />
                </a>
              );
            }
            case "instagram": {
              debugger;
              return (
                <a href={soc.link}>
                  jvgvvuv
                  <Instagram />
                </a>
              );
            }
            case "facebook": {
              return (
                <a href={soc.link}>
                  <Facebook />
                </a>
              );
            }
            case "twitter": {
              return (
                <a href={soc.link}>
                  <Twitter />
                </a>
              );
            }
            default:
              return null;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  };
  return (
      <div className="status">
        <p>{props.aboutMe}</p>
        <div className={s.user_links}>{social()}</div>
        <div className={s.friends_block}>
          <h5>Friends:</h5>
          <div className={s.my_friends}>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: It seems that it's missing a `return` on this line `return props.social.map`

Comment: You did not return anything from your social function

Comment: @MoufeedJuboqji what do you mean? there is a switch that needs to return jsx

Comment: you did switch inside the map but you need to return the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just misses return at this line: `props.social.map((soc) => {`

It needs to be: `return props.social.map((soc) => {`